# How to do code-free Azure Storage Integration with SharePoint Online (Office 365)

Tags: sharepoint, azure, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-online

Could you please help me on Azure and Office 365 Integration.

**Requirement :** Currently, I have a site which is developed in SharePoint Online 2013. Where we have a section for software, which are saved in a different server (FTP Sever). And we have added those FTP links in our page.

**Example:**  which is hyper-linked with external FTP URL :  *ftp:///SoftwareName(it may be .zip, or .exe or any kind of setup file)*

Whenever authorized person want to download the s/w, the user will be redirected to FTP.

We are facing slowness issue with our FTP server, so now we want to save those softwares in Azure Storage.

- Please guide me which azure storage will be suitable for us?
- How to upload software in Azure without writing a single line of code.
- Can we use the Azure Storage as FTP server, where we can save/upload/delete/update the software
- If user is logged in into SharePoint Online (Office 365), will Azure require the login again? while accessing/downloading the software, if we get all things(Azure and SharePoint Online) under one tenant.
- The software download page which is created in SharePoint Online,  is accessible by few user or groups. Can same group of user have login access to Azure to download the software? is it possible ? (Because in our existing environment, we have given FTP access to limited user, only they can download the s/w, when they access the link, it's asking for username and password).

Thanks in advance!

Kind Regards,
Virendra Kumar

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Azure offers multiple services, one of which is the Azure Storage. The Azure Store service is meant to be used by applications; not by end users directly. So there is no built-in interface for end users to login and interact with the storage environment. Because Azure Storage is a Platform as a Service (PaaS), you must write code to interact with it.

While there is a relationship between Microsoft Azure and Office365, the link is mostly for storing user credentials in the Azure Directory Services; but again, it's a service meant to be used by applications (Office365 is an application that consumes the Directory Service of Azure). You can't use these logins to access anything else in Azure.

Because there is a fundamental gap between what you are trying to achieve and what the Microsoft Azure platform offers, your questions are difficult to answer directly. There is no FTP service equivalent in Microsoft Azure at this time.

If you are ready to code your own webparts however, you might be able to implement this yourself, but it may require a significant effort. Here is a link to a blog post that talks about building [custom webparts for Office365](http://sp365.co.uk/2011/07/build-a-simple-web-part-for-office-365-that-gets-data-from-a-list/). If instead of reading from a list, as the blog post suggests, you read from an Azure Storage account, you would list your applications this way.

Comment: Herve, Thank you so much for the response.